# How to display CJK Extension G?

Tags: fonts

Wikipedia has a page entitled [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_G).

- I've installed BabelStone's [BabelHan](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) but coverage isn't 100%:

> Unicode Block  | Total Coverage Characters | Percentage    | G-Source Coverage Characters  | Percentage
>
> CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G | 2,447 / 4,939 | 49.5% | 569 / 2,082   | 27.3%

- [天珩全字库](http://zisea.com/download/) doesn't look like it's been updated for ext. G.
- [Hanazono](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/), likewise, hasn't been updated yet.

How to display CJK Extension G?

Comment: I think you'll know the answer: find a font that covers all characters in it. If there is not any available now, then we can only wait, or make a font by ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://zhs.glyphwiki.org/wiki/Group:sim-ch_n5100
Here, download the font, cover 100% Ext-G

Answer (score 2):

You did well to install BabelStone Han: it has currently the best cover so far. The extension has just been released, and there have been no immediate fonts to match that. GlyphWiki.org contains all the glyphs but not yet combined in a font of Hanazono series. So the best think you can do for a while is to follow the development of BabelStone Han. (Or write to kawabata at https://github.com/kawabata and ask them to generate the new entry in the Hanazono-AFDKO fonts for Extension G.)

By the way, several of the high-profile glyphs are available elsewhere: if you need the 3106C “taito,” 30EDE/30EDD “biang,” or the character 30729 which was the only missing character for Korean names, they are available in Source Han Sans. (Only, I believe, not under their Unicode codes, but accessible through the composition by their IDS.)

Comment: Yeah, I’ve already emailed Koichi Kamichi, I’ll see what he says.

Answer (score 2):

天珩全字库 seem already been updated for ext. G.
http://cheonhyeong.com/Simplified/download.html

【天珩全字库(TH-Tshyn)
7z(手动安装)版
exe(Windows安装程序)版   目前字符数量最全的字体支持包，其中汉字部分支持14余万，主要设计为大陆风格。另外本字库有Unicode13.0以内的所有字符，包括但不限于表情符号(黑白色)。[字库中修复了数百个汉字的错误字形，如“膥”、“槩”、“肞”、“褝”等，也从未见其他字库有过任何与之相同或相似的操作，请放心使用！]】

天珩字庫-「天珩全字庫V3.0.0」安裝使用說明(Windows用)
……(包括但不限於表情符號、小語種等所有Unicode13.0所定義的字元)……
編譯日期：2020年5月31日

沈天珩

2020年5月31日

TH-fonts-"TH-Tshyn V3.0.0"Description of Using and Installing (For Windows)
……(contains all the characters in Unicode13.0, like the emojis, small languages and so on).……
Font style: MIXTURE

Compile date: May 31, 2020

Sim Cheon Hyeong

2020-06-01

【★　本字庫包含近二十萬標準字元，其中中日韓越統一表意文字有14萬2千多：

CJK基本　　　[4E00-9FFF]    20992碼位　實際20989字
　　CJK擴充A　　 [3400-4DBF]     6592碼位　實際 6592字
　　CJK擴充B　　 [20000-2A6DF]  42720碼位　實際42718字
　　CJK擴充C　　 [2A700-2B73F]   4160碼位　實際 4149字
　　CJK擴充D　　 [2B740-2B81F]  　224碼位　實際  222字
　　CJK擴充E　　 [2B820-2CEAF]   5776碼位　實際 5762字
　　CJK擴充F　　 [2CEB0-2EBEF]   7488碼位　實際 7473字
　　CJK擴充G　　 [30000-3134F]   4944碼位　實際 4939字
　　CJK兼容      [F900-FAFF]    　512碼位　實際  472字
　　CJK兼容擴充  [2F800-2FA1F]  　544碼位　實際  542字
　　PUA增補 　　 [E000-F4FF]   　5376碼位　實際 2288字
　　SPUA增補　　 [100000-10C7BF]51136碼位　實際46490字
】
[image]

---

### another font for ext.-G is :

http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/bujian/KaiXinSong.php

【开心宋体 3.0

能显示cjk-a,b,c,d,e,f,g区所有汉字
还有康熙部首及兼容字等10万个字符
能显示 FG区汉字的字体几乎没有
这个可以完美显示FG区汉字
经过测试能完全能显示出所有Unicode汉字

A：cjk基本区、cjk-A及兼容字
B：cjk-B-G区

由于win7以上的系统都能完美显示基本区和A区汉字，所以KaiXinSongA可以不用安装，这个不是必须的。
字体B包含B-G区所有汉字，大部分电脑都不能完全显示，这个必须安装。……】

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plangothic (遍黑体) has complete coverage of CJK Extension G.

https://github.com/Fitzgerald-Porthmouth-Koenigsegg/Plangothic

Note: You only need P2 for Extension G. P1 has coverage for URO - Extension F.

Answer (score 0):

Source Han Sans and Serif has been updated to Ext. G.